# Tag wiki excerpts - suggestions without usage guidance

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

In the last days I saw a bunch of edit suggestions for wiki tag excerpts that merely described what the tag was about but without any **usage guidance**.

I rejected them all with this reason but most of them were approved afterwards.

Are they really ok?

- https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/495537
- https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/495538
- https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/495536
- https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/495379
- https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/495375

There are more of them, most (if not all) by the same user.

Comment: The only two which need it IMO are `screen-reader` (maybe) and `rtl8192cu` (which I'm not entirely sure we even need, but I may well be wrong on this, since I don't attend wifi tags at all). I can't see how you could misuse `strace` `xsnow` and `pcsx`, unless there's another application with the same name; anyway even then you have the description as a guidance. Maybe I'm missing something though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a tag is just a bunch of letters (eg PCSX), a definition is useful to ensure they aren't being misused. I completely agree that *also* specifying usage might make it better, I just don't think there's no value in the definition... Which is what you're saying when you reject.

I also agree with kos, that some tags are pretty self-explanatory. It's either about PCSX or it's not. There's no benefit from having a "Use this tag when it's about PCSX". Most tags will imply that.